# Why lst.add(2) for ArrayList<Long> gives compile error instead of calling add(Long) method?

Tags: java, arraylist, overloading

There are 2 overridden methods in ArrayList:

> public boolean add(E e)
>
> public void add(int index, E element)

What are the general rules, according to which `add(longArg)` cannot box it and call `add(E e)`, giving me compile error (thus actually prohibiting me from overloded call to `add(E e)`:

```
    ArrayList<Long> lst = new ArrayList<>();            
    lst.add(2); // c.ERR, see below
         // method add(int, Long) in the type ArrayList<Long> 
        // is not applicable for the arguments (int)
```

P.S.  Eclipse (SE7) compiler.

Comment: Because it needs to be widened and autoboxed to add, but it won't do both automatically.

Comment: eclipse is not a compiler

Comment: eclipse has it's own implementation of a Java compiler, giving different error messages, allowing to continue to compile after errors,....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are trying to add an `integer`. If you instruct the compiler to consider it to be a `long` add a `L` or `l` to the number

```
 ArrayList<Long> lst = new ArrayList<>();            
 lst.add(2L); // now it can be autoboxed
```

Executed in Java 9's [JShell](https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/new-for-java-9:-jshell):

```
jshell>  ArrayList<Long> lst = new ArrayList<>();            
lst ==> []

jshell> lst.add(2);
|  Error:
|  no suitable method found for add(int)
|      method java.util.Collection.add(java.lang.Long) is not applicable
|        (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to java.lang.Long)
|      method java.util.List.add(java.lang.Long) is not applicable
|        (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to java.lang.Long)
|      method java.util.AbstractCollection.add(java.lang.Long) is not applicable
|        (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to java.lang.Long)
|      method java.util.AbstractList.add(java.lang.Long) is not applicable
|        (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to java.lang.Long)
|      method java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Long) is not applicable
|        (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to java.lang.Long)
|  lst.add(2);
|  ^-----^

jshell> lst.add(2l);
$2 ==> true
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use generics you will have to include a reference to a type of object that is going in the List. In this case you are trying to tell the ArrayList to reference only values of type long, or int or double, etc...

You need to declare the objects that will be referenced in a generic by using big D Double and Big I Integer and Big L Long as these are object types.

I'm not too sure if you can box a Long as an object type but check your API and you will see.

Hope this code works:

```
ArrayList<Long> lst = new ArrayList<Long>();
```